Panel timeline is odd on Splunk dashboard
I have crated a Splunk dashboard that will display two quantities in two panels.
index=unix | bin span=10m _time
and
index=windows | bin span=10m _time.
Obviously these two indexes will have different characteristics over time. Assume windows will provide data only in the 8am-10am window and linux will provide data points in the 9am-11am window.
When I setup the time span on my dasboard to show data over the last 24 hours then the Windows chart left point will be 8am and 10am is the right side. Also the Linux chart most left point will be 9am and 11am will be the rightmost point on the x-axis.
I want the chart to be shown as the left most point to be now()-24h and the rightmost point to be now(). or at least I want to sync both panels so when they show up above each oher then I can easiliy identify time. So the timelines are synced.
How would that be possible?
